# Blackberry application wait 1 second before pushing a new screen

Tags: blackberry, sleep, wait

So, basically I have 2 screens.

The first screen is an introduction screen, it just displays a logo. This screen is simply pushed onto the stack first.

The second screen is the main screen. Which is not pushed onto the stack yet.

I want the application to pause on the intro screen for 1 second then push the main screen onto the stack.

How would i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`invokeLater()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20boolean%29)?  You could do something like this:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyMainScreen());
    }
}, 1000, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the best approach uses invokeLater, as Scott indicated. However you might also want to close that initial screen (startScreen), or else pressing back will show it again:

```
    MainApp.homeScreen = new HomeScreen();
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(MainApp.homeScreen);
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(MainApp.startScreen);
        }
    }, 2000, false);
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if there is a special function for that, I'm not familiar with it.

But you could create your own wait method: `wait(1000)`

Then you create a wait function with 1 parameter (the amount of time) and create a while loop as long as the difference between starttime and now is smaller than the parameter.

Comment: hmm, this sounds like a busy-wait loop to me... sure it's only for 1 second, but still not very nice.

Comment: I haven't worked with BB yet, so I don't know if there's a setTimeout or so.

But that function simulates a wait function so that should work I think.

Comment: This would block the main UI thread which is bad. As a result user may not even see the first screen, since there is no free CPU cycles to paint it.

Comment: Isn't that what he wants? To show the introduction screen, wait a second and then show the other screen?

Or am I wrong here..

Comment: this is not the best approach, programmatically speaking.
what the question author wants, is to display a logo screen, THEN display the second screen (main application screen, etc)